# Fetching subdivision categories from GeoNames using location coordinates?

Tags: latitude-longitude, geonames

I'm looking for an API where I can get second level subdivision(ISO 3166-2) if I pass longitude and latitude.

Second level subdivision code reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:GB

Eg.

`Lat/Lon: 51.5033630,-0.1276250`

The value I want is GB-LND as a return.

I've tried following but I want more specific codes:

```
api.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=51.5033630&lng=-0.1276250&username=demo
api.geonames.org/countrySubdivision?lat=51.5033630&lng=-0.1276250&username=demo
```